# How do I create a Mailer Observer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, observer-pattern, actionmailer

I'd like to run some code whenever an email is sent on my app.

As ActionMailer doesn't support after_filter, I would like to use an observer.

The Rails docs mention this in passing, however does not elaborate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I'm surprised how little there is in Rails' documentation about this.

Basically, ActionMailer in Rails 3 introduces the use of Interceptors (called before the message is sent) and Observers (after the message is sent).

To set up an Observer, add the following to an initializer:

```
class MailObserver
  def self.delivered_email(message)
    # Do whatever you want with the message in here
  end
end

ActionMailer::Base.register_observer(MailObserver)
```

Now, the `delivered_email` method will run every time your app sends an e-mail. However, you will only have access to the actual `Mail` message.

To register an Interceptor instead, do the same as above, replacing `register_observer` with `register_interceptor`, and renaming the method from `self.delivered_email` to `self.delivering_email`.

[This Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3) was the best source I could find for info on this (they only talk about interceptors, but the concept is the same for observers).

Comment: Thanks dmarkow, this is exactly what I was looking for, and as you said, information is scarce, especialy when you don't know the term "Interceptors" is one to look for.

Comment: This raises some more questions - (1) How would you tell which mailer and which method was used, (2) How would you observe failure and (3) How would you test this, including the failure case?