# Mailer result as String?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

In our custom sales app our users are able to send emails based on text partials they choose. We need to record the sent mails in an activity model. How do I get the mailer result as a string in order to save it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling the deliver method to send the mail, you can capture the email message by calling to_s. For example, if you have a mailer:

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default :from => "sender@me.com"

  def my_email
    mail(:to => "destination@you.com", :subject => "Mail Subject")
  end

end
```

you would do

```
mail_content = MyMailer.my_email.to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can using a mail observer like in the following example :

```
class MailObserver
    def self.delivered_email(message)
         test = Activty.create do |activity|
             # etc.
         end
    end
end
```

Find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850484/how-do-i-create-a-mailer-observer)