# Best way to monitor rails mailer activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, actionmailer

I have a mailer(triggered by a rake task) that sends deals to users based on a few different factors (gender, location, age ect).

Everything is working great I just need a way to monitor and report how many emails are sent out to report to our customers.

Whats the best way to monitor email activity in a rails app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use observer.

The answer about how to use it is here: [How do I create a Mailer Observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850484/how-do-i-create-a-mailer-observer)