# Save each email before sending rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I want to keep track of all triggered emails by the application into a db table, so that i can have a log which emails are sent and to whom.

Kindly suggest me the best possible solution.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850484/how-do-i-create-a-mailer-observer/5131614#5131614

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have solved this using the following way:

created a class in lib directory

```
class MyProjectMailLogger

  def self.delivering_email(message)
   @to = message.to.to_s
   @subject = message.subject.to_s
   @message = message.body.to_s
   EmailQueue.create!(:receipient_email => @to, :subject => @subject, :message => @message, :email_status_id => 3)
 end

end
```

In config/initalizers/setup_mail.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(MyProjectMailLogger)
```

You might need to add the following line in the application.rb file as its not include files from lib directory:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Yay!! and i logged my emails.

Comment: I had to implement something very similar to your solution, except I used ActionMailer::Base.register_observer(..) for that. This worked well, but now I have to implement a way to re-send any of the emails from the "email log", with all attachments. Now wondering how do I do that...

Answer (score 0):

I am doing some research on this and it seems like https://github.com/ankane/ahoy_email is a nice gem to accomplish this. It [uses an interceptor internally](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy_email/blob/master/lib/ahoy_email/interceptor.rb) like the accepted answer. It also integrates with a [free event tracking library](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy) that has a number of different backends. Might be something to consider if you're starting something like this today.